# printf() changing treatment of variable in C

Tags: c, variables, loops, printf

I have a pretty simple function in my program using the secant method to find a root of a function. It works fine with the printf() that's indicated below. But if I comment it out, the loop endlessly repeats. I have no idea why...

I've read about printf changing a variable, but I don't see anything on it changing the storage of the variable. Am I missing something? It's not a great solution to have it print, since the iterates are not important and the function is called millions of times.

```
double guess1=500.;
double y1=estimater(r,volume,guess1,adm,tm,rr[r]);
double guess2=adm/30.;
double y2=estimater(r,volume,guess2,adm,tm,rr[r]);
int i;
double guess3=0.;
double y3;
double tol =heightTOL;
int secmax=SECANTMAX;
for(i=1;i<=secmax;i++){
    guess3=guess2-y2*(guess2-guess1)/(y2-y1);
    if(guess3>adm/2.){
        guess3=adm/2.;
    }
    if(guess3<=0.){
        guess3=0.;
    }
    y3=estimater(r,volume,guess3,adm,tm,rr[r]);
    y1=y2;
    y2=y3;
    guess1=guess2;
    guess2=guess3;
    if(fabs(guess2-guess1)<tol){
        break;
    }
    if(i==secmax){
        printf("\nRan out of iterations in height finder\n");
    }
    printf("%d     %f",i,guess3); //THIS ONE HERE!!!!!!!!
}
return guess3;
```

Comment: You are probably invoking undefined behaviour somewhere.  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that we can compile and run?

Comment: My best guess: You're writing outside the bounds of an array, `rr[r]` is the only candidate I see, and that overwrites `i` so that `i == secmax` never becomes true, unless the call to `printf` causes a layout change that moves `i` to a place it's not (yet) stepped on.

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger? Or if you're on linux, through valgrind to check for memory errors?

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is not changing your data at all.  The only way the `printf` family of functions can have any effect on your data is if you use the `%n` format specifier (which writes into the variable whose address you pass) or if you're doing something which invokes undefined behavior, like passing the wrong format arguments.  You're not doing either of those things here (your format strings are correct), so your bug lies elsewhere.

Check that all your array accesses are in bounds.  Try running your code in Valgrind or other validators to try to find memory errors.